# keeping an image onscreen after rotation

Tags: android, imageview, rotation

My app generates a bitnap which is saved to the disk immediately after it is created. It is then displayed in an imageview. I want the UI of the app to be able to rotate, but the image is not restored after rotation. I cannot save it to a bundle to restore it after rotation.

How do I keep it onscreen?

Comment: do you want Activity to get restarted on orientation change? If not then use `configChanges` to stop re-creation of Activity on orientation change.

Comment: I am currently doing that, and redrawing the bitmap with every orientation change. But then any text entered in edittexts is wiped. Leaving orientation changes to the OS keeps text in the fields when the activity is recreated. How do I save that then?

Comment: Simple text strings and integers can be saved in the Bundle during onInstanceSave(). For objects see my link below.